# Braintree PayPal Sandbox keeps redirecting

Tags: android, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have added a simple non drop-in paypal integration in sandbox mode to my app. Here is a test activity with a single "Pay" button:

```
public class PaypalPaymentAcivity extends Activity implements PaymentMethodNonceCreatedListener {

private BraintreeFragment mBraintreeFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paypal);
    findViewById(R.id.payButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startPayment();
        }
    });
}

private void startPayment() {
    try {
        mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(this, "...");
        PayPalRequest request = new PayPalRequest("1")
                .currencyCode("USD")
                .intent(PayPalRequest.INTENT_AUTHORIZE);
        PayPal.requestOneTimePayment(mBraintreeFragment, request);
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPaymentMethodNonceCreated(PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce) {

}
}
```

However once the PayPal browser window comes up after clicking the buttons it just keeps popping up over and over, and never returns to my activity.

Anyone had a successful integration like this?

Comment: Can you clarify `keeps popping up over and over`? What actions are you seeing that are unexpected?

Comment: Hey. When I click on the "Pay" button in the browser (the checkout.paypal.com window comes uo) the window simply reopens without anything else happing.